# Deploy website to azure with bower dependencies

Tags: azure, deployment, bower, azure-web-app-service

I have an ASPNET mvc project using both Nuget and Bower for dependencies. Now I need to either trigger bower to install components upon deployment or as fallback include the packages by allowing them in my .gitignore. Of course I would like to not include those in the repo and just have them installed while deploying, just like with nuget packages. I tried to follow this guide http://gregtrowbridge.com/deploying-a-bower-dependent-node-app-on-windows-azure/ but still nothing seems to happen. So any help is welcome :)

Best regards

Comment: are you using git to deploy your site?

Comment: Yes plain git deployment from bitbucket

Answer (score 15, accepted):

All of Azure Websites workers have bower pre-installed and should be on your path.

All you need to do is add a custom deployment script that would do `bower install`
[Here is a sample repo for an ASP.NET MVC site that uses bower](https://github.com/ahmelsayed-test/MvcWithBower)

Basically make sure bower.json is there and [referenced in your `csproj`](https://github.com/ahmelsayed-test/MvcWithBower/blob/master/MvcWithBower.csproj#L105)

```
    <Content Include="bower.json" />
```

Then download your custom deployment script. if you go to `https://<yourSiteName>.scm.azurewebsites.net` then click on `Tools -> Download custom deployment script` or just download it from `D:\home\deployment\tools` then check it in the root of your [repo like here](https://github.com/ahmelsayed-test/MvcWithBower/commit/537b3118b50029c75db3bfc11dba2b2212cf1c9e) basically there will be 2 files `deploy.cmd` and `.deployment`

this is the deployment logic, add a step to restore bower in it [like here](https://github.com/ahmelsayed-test/MvcWithBower/commit/502ba86e141e5b14c2fbf07933b176ee0cd9c6bf) after the last step there

```
:: 4. Bower Install
if EXIST "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%\bower.json" (
    pushd "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%"
    call :ExecuteCmd bower install
    IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
    popd
)
```

Comment: Will have to verify this again as i already tried this. Maybe I forgot to exclude some of the bower packages in .gitignore

Comment: try to deploy the repo I linked to and see if that works for restoring the correct bower components in the correct locations. You can browse the content of your site easily if you navigate to `https://<siteName>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole` then see what's different in your repo I guess and why restoring isn't happening

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I had an error in an external lib, and after some log reading and scm investigation is worked. Thanks for the tip

Comment: This worked for me, however, I needed to update the `IF EXISTS` part of the script about where to find the bower.json file. I have multiple projects in my solution, so I ended up with something like this:

`if EXIST "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\PROJECT_FOLDER\bower.json" (
        pushd "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\PROJECT_FOLDER"
        call :ExecuteCmd bower install
        IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
        popd`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **console** feature of Azure web app to fire the commands. Even if the console has access to a restricted features, you can still install the bower components by using the command:

```
bower install
```

The console option is listed under the deployment section of the Web Apps. You can refer the below the screen for reference.

[image: Screen 1]

Prerequisites:

1. Do not publish the **bowerComponents** folder to the Web app.
2. Include the **bower.json** file including all the dependencies.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

One important addition to the above - you must push both the unchanged .deployment file and modified .cmd file to deployment root for Azure to subsequently copy/execute your .cmd amendments. Otherwise it will regenerate a default .cmd