# Install Bower Components in Azure Web App using ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, bower, bower-install, azure-resource-manager

I am currently working on ARM templates and have successfully deployed an app as an Azure web app. I have also successfully installed the bower components using the console feature of Azure web apps. You can find a reference for the same [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43840563/2802017).

Now, I want to automate all this stuff using ARM templates but don't know how to install the bower components using ARM.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You are doing this at the wrong place. The packages should be installed in the build, and then the artifacts contain the packages you are deploying in the release. ARM is for deploying/configuring you infrastructure, the js packages are part of you application.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this link [Using Bower in Node.js Azure WebApps](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2016/01/25/using-bower-in-node-js-azure-webapps/) on how to install bower in your web app. It's not done during ARM orchestration of the appservice infrastructure, but rather during a deployment or a build.